# django: Add user popup. Missing fields (first_name, last_name)

Tags: python, django

I have UserProfile defined this way

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

This model is registered in admin. And when I am adding a user from UserProfile (e.g. clicking + near the users dropdown), I am getting a popup, with just email and two passwords pair. 
Is there any way to get first_name and last_name in the same popup? Why are they missing?

note: I am using `emailusernames` application inside the project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add user at `admin/auth/user/add/`.
You will see what you see in popup - form for username and password.
After creating user you will be redirected to created user, where you will be able to fill other information.

Look at django admin template sources:

```
{% block form_top %}
  {% if not is_popup %}
    <p>{% trans "First, enter a username and password. Then, you'll be able to edit more user options." %}</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>{% trans "Enter a username and password." %}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's telling us that by default you can add more info after object creation.

Here also are forms:
`django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm` and `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`

It's telling us the same.

At django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin replacing `add_fieldsets` by

```
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')}
    ),
)
```

gives the result, but it is not good, because we a editing souce code of django.

So at my admin.py i wrote this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
UserAdmin.add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')}
        ),
    )
```

It is a little bit hacky, but doing stuff well.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) you can extends UserAdmin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = BaseUserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)
        }),
    )
```

and unregister User

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
```

And register with new UserAdmin

```
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You can also add UserProfile in UserAdmin

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'user profile'


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)

    add_fieldsets = BaseUserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)
        }),
    )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```